# Toggle text view visibility in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I'm working with a `GridView` and was trying to toggle the visibility of a Text View within each Grid Item. I am using a custom adapter and have implemented the relevant code and changed the `android:visibility` also.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Players> playerList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Players> playerList){
    this.context = context;
    this.playerList = playerList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return playerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_grid_item, null);

    TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_id);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
    TextView roleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_role);

    Players p = new Players();
    p = playerList.get(position);
    idTextView.setText("ID " + String.valueOf(p.getId()));
    nameTextView.setText("Name " + String.valueOf(p.getName()));
    roleTextView.setText("Role " + String.valueOf(p.getRole()));
    toggleView(roleTextView);



    return convertView;
}

public void toggleView(View view){
    if(view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}

}
```

**layout_grid_item.xml**

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_player_role"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="role" />
```

**fragment_viewroles.xml** (GRID VIEW)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tuss.mafia.GameActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_players"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center" >
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml set clickable to true

```
<TextView
  android:onClick="onClick"
  android:clickable="true" 
  />
```

use this method

```
public void toggleView(View view){
    if(view.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else if(view.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

and call it like

```
toggleView(roleTextView);
```

final product

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_grid_item, null);

    TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_id);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
    TextView roleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_role);

    Players p = new Players();
    p = playerList.get(position);
    idTextView.setText("ID " + String.valueOf(p.getId()));
    nameTextView.setText("Name " + String.valueOf(p.getName()));
    roleTextView.setText("Role " + String.valueOf(p.getRole()));


//If you want to show text by default
roleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//If you want to hide text by default
roleTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

roleTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleView(view);
            }
        });    


    return convertView;
}

public void toggleView(View view){
    if(view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it is still not working, I removed `visibility: gone`  and so far the text box stays hidden, not responding to touch.

Comment: Can you post your grid view xml?

Comment: Thank you for posting code. Do you have another view in another layout file with the id .tv_player_id?

Comment: No problem. There aren't any other usages of tv_player_id

Comment: Ok i edited my answer, after you initialize the view, set whether you want the textview to be visible or not (i included both in there for you, delete the line you don't need). Then set your onclick listener to toggle the view when they click on it. It might be hard for them to click it again if its invisible so you might want to make it visible from some other method in your code, i.e when they click a different button, make the textview visible again

Answer (score 0):

```
if (R.id.tv_player_role == View.VISIBLE) {}
```

this wrong
you need to do it with `isShown()` method

```
if(roleTextView.isShown()){
//it is visible so do something
} 
else {
//it is invisible
}
```

or use `view.getVisibility()`

Answer (score 0):

inside `public void onClick(View v)` method of `View.OnClickListener`

```
if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
```

also note `roleTextView` visibility is set in XML to `gone`, so if you are not toggling it by code then there is nothing to click on screen (`setText` is not sufficient, or you cutted to much code)...

use `inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_grid_item, parent, false);` for better performance and if needed implement `ViewHolder` pattern as other fellas suggested

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I have updated to show my full MyAdapter class.

Comment: inside `toggleView` method you are checking if `View`s visibility is `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE`, but in XML you have `android:visibility="gone"`. Both "if" checks are `false` so method do nothing at all... change XML line to `android:visibility="invisible"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all use View Holder pattern with List and Grid always. It reduce lots of problem regarding view load during scroll.

Now for your issue you have to keep maintain index of view for which you have hidden text view and for which you have not. so when grid scroll it check for position and then decide weather to display text view or not. 
Check this tutorial for storing index for each row(Just a reference) - http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html